# Put the filename and the filetype in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filenames

I want to put the filename and the filetype in a array and I know the answer (`split`) but I don't know how to look for the last dot before the extension begin.

Examples: `Funny - SMS 02.jpg` will get `Funny - SMS 02`in one array and `jpg` in another. But when I'm try to split the name of an file that already contains dots, the trouble begins. `Funny - When you see it....jpg` prints `Funny - When you see it` in for example `fname[0]` and `jpg` in `fname[1]`.

How can I make it print `Funny - When you see it...` as `fname[0]` and `jpg` as `fname[1]`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 fname = "Funny - When you see it....jpg"
 parts = fname.split(/\.(?=[^.]*$)/) 
 // parts=["Funny - When you see it...", "jpg"]
```

`?=` is called 'lookahead' and basically means "followed by". So, the above reads: "split by a dot if there's no dots after it".

Comment: This worked the same as Tom's function. I'll use yours because of the one-lined solution :) Thanks!

Comment: @ErikEdgren: our functions behave differently if a filename contains no dots at all or one single dot at the end (I corrected my code slightly for the latter case).

Comment: Ah. Okej. Then I'm aware of that :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
function getFnameExt(filename) {
  var parts = filename.split('.'), ext = parts.pop(), fname = parts.join('.');
  return [ fname, ext ];
}

console.log( getFnameExt("Funny - When you see it....jpg") );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = [];
var s = "Funny - When you see it....jpg";
var lastDot = s.lastIndexOf(".");
array[0] = s.substring(0, lastDot);
array[1] = s.substring(lastDot + 1);
alert(array[0] + "---" + array[1]);
```

Comment: That worked very well! :D Many thanks! I'll mark it when I can.

Answer (score 1):

For these kinds of tasks splitting is usually cumbersome. Regular expressions are more powerful:

```
var matches = /^(.*)\.([^.]*)$/g.exec("Funny - When you see it....jpg");
matches.shift();

// matches:
// ["Funny - When you see it...", "jpg"]
```

This matches the string against the regexp, which results in an array with three elements. The first is the full match which is not needed, so shift it.

```
^       begin of string
.*      any amount of any character
\.      a dot
[^.]*   any amount of any character except a dot
$       end of string
```

With the begin/end of string anchors, `.*` must contain all characters before the last dot.

`(` and `)` denote a group, which adds the matched substring to the array.